# Possible to mirror DNS forward lookup zone to second TLD? (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

We recently started using a new TLD for our company, but are still maintaining the old TLD.

On our local DNS server (Windows Server 2012) we have internal DNS records set up as subdomains of the old TLD, and I'd like to also get them set up with the new TLD. Is it possible to create an alias between the two TLDs, or to somehow mirror the forward lookup zone? I'd rather not have to maintain two forward lookup zones that are exact duplicates of each other.

To illustrate, we have these two TLDs:

- `example1.com`
- `example2.com`

We have a internal subdomains set up that point to our local network:

- `internal.example1.com`
- `internal.example2.com`

And then we have sub-subdomains like so:

- `router.internal.example1.com`
- `printer1.internal.example1.com`
- etc...

I want to set up all the subdomains in `example2.com` to automatically resolve using the definitions in the `example1.com` forward lookup zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `DNAME` record at the base (sub)domain where you want the aliasing to start. For example, if you want to alias all subdomains of "internal.example1.com", create:

```
internal.example2.com. DNAME internal.example1.com.
```

Everything "under" this name in the domain tree will be aliased as if you had 'CNAME'd each name individually (in fact, you will see the nameserver produce CNAMEs on the fly when queried).

Note though that the aliased names *are not* actually copied to the new zone; eventually you will need to do that manually (maybe using LDAP or editing the zone file).

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you! I couldn't find the answer to this question because I didn't know the term DNAME.